# Generalized C# Method for Handling an Event Once and Then Unsubscribing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, generics, events, delegates

I'm trying to devise a generalized way of implementing what I believe is a pretty common pattern of needing to handle a class event exactly once in order to set a `TaskCompletionSource` result, and unsubscribe immediately. The pattern looks like this:

```
Task DoSomethingAfterAnEventHasBeenTriggeredOnceAsync() 
{
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
     SomeEventHandlerDelegate handler = null;
     handler = new SomeEventHandlerDelegate((p1,p2,p3) => 
     {
        // do my thing
        // ...
        someObj.SomeEvent -= handler;
        tcs.SetResult(null);
     });
     someObj.SomeEvent += handler;
     return tcs.Task;
}
```

My initial thought was to make a generic method along these lines:

```
    public static Task SubscribeOnceAsync<Tsender, Tdel>(
        Tdel handler,
        Action<Tdel> addHandler, 
        Action<Tdel> removeHandler)
        where Tdel: System.Delegate
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        // ???
        // somehow create a new delegate to send to 
        // "addHandler" that calls "handler",
        // then calls "removeHandler", and then
        // sets the tcs result
        // ???
    }
```

That would be consumed like this:

```
     INotifyPropertyChanged inpc; 
     // ...
     await SubscribeOnceAsync<INotifyPropertyChanged, PropertyChangedEventHandler>(
         (s, e) =>
         {                
             // do my one time thing
         },
         (s, h) => inpc.PropertyChanged += h, 
         (s, h) => inpc.PropertyChanged -= h);
```

The problem is in dynamically creating the delegate that can be provided to `addHandler` and `removeHandler`. With `Delegate.Combine` the two delegates have to be the same type, so I actually would have to dynamically create a delegate of type `Tdel` that called `removeHandler` and `tcs.SetResult`.

I suppose it might be possible to do something with dynamic compilation but this is ultimately going to be used with .NET WASM so I'm wary of going down that route given how ill tempered that runtime can be.

So I'm not even sure if my initial thinking is the best way to do this but can't think of any other ways to tackle this. Any ideas?

Note this would need to work with existing code that use `event`s, so the `IObservable` pattern is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the event to be declared as

```cs
public EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> SomeEvent;
```

My idea is to provide a proxy delegate which unsubscribes the event and then executes the original delegate (I called it `action`).

```cs
public static Task SubscribeOnceAsync<TArgs>(
    Action<EventHandler<TArgs>> addHandler,
    Action<EventHandler<TArgs>> removeHandler,
    Action<object, TArgs> action) where TArgs : EventArgs
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    addHandler(Proxy); 
    return tcs.Task;
           
    void Proxy(object sender, TArgs args)
    {
        removeHandler(Proxy);
        action(sender, args);
        tcs.SetResult(null);
    }
}
```

Note that `Proxy` is declared as local function which captures `removeHandler` and `action`. Therefore, it does not require them to be passed as extra parameters and has therefore the same signature as the original event handler.

It would be consumed like this:

```cs
static async Task TestSubscribeOnceAsync()
{
    var someObj = new EventClass();

    await SubscribeOnceAsync<SomeEventArgs>(
        eh => someObj.SomeEvent += eh,
        eh => someObj.SomeEvent -= eh,
        (sender, args) => {
            Console.WriteLine("do my thing");
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Ooh, now this is why I'm glad I posted this question. I never would've thought to do a local function. That's intriguing. Let me play with this a little and see if I can make this work. I would like it to be ideally a little more generalized than just `EventHandler<T>` so there may be no way around making several overloads of this, one for each # of arguments supported, but that's still a one time deal. Thank you, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: The idea is to have one argument class having as many properties as you need parameters: `EventHandler<MyArgumentsWithFiveParameters>`. Therefore, you need only one overload. You can even return results form an event handler through these parameters.

Comment: Right but I want this to work with objects /events I don't control, like INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Yeah, so I tried a lot of permutations with this - and it definitely works great with anything that follows the `EventHandler<T>` pattern, but unfortunately the issue of delegate typing seems to remain unavoidable if we want to use it with code that doesn't follow that pattern. I can't seem to get the compiler to accept the inline function as a viable source for a generic delegate type to the point where it could be `+=`-able. I came up with a potential solution using a class which I'll post as an answer in the hopes that you or someone else can think of improvements.

Comment: But don't get me wrong, this is a great option thank you. If you don't mind I'm gonna suggest some edits to fit the `TaskCompletionSource` pattern I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, which uses classes instead of static methods. Delegate typing turns out to be a significant challenge here if we want to support any generalized `event`, in existing code or elsehwere.

This isn't the most elegant looking code, and it does have an inherent limitation, but it's pretty usable in practice.

First, the base class:

```
public class OneTimeObserver<Tsender, Tdel, Tdelarg1, Tdelarg2, Tdelarg3, Tdelarg4, Tdelarg5>
    where Tdel : Delegate
{
    Tdel _theirDel;
    Tdel _ourDel;
    Action<Tsender, Tdel> _unsub;
    TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs;
    Tsender _sender;

    protected OneTimeObserver(
        Tsender sender,
        Tdel del,
        Action<Tsender, Tdel> sub,
        Action<Tsender, Tdel> unsub,
        int argCount)
    {
        _sender = sender;
        _unsub = unsub;
        _theirDel = del;
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        string methodName = $"Observe{argCount}";

        _ourDel = (Tdel)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Tdel), this, methodName);
        sub(_sender, _ourDel);
    }

    public Task Task => _tcs.Task;

    protected void Observe0()
    {
        _unsub(_sender, _ourDel);
        _theirDel?.DynamicInvoke();
        _tcs.SetResult(null);
    }

    protected void Observe1(Tdelarg1 arg1)
    {
        _unsub(_sender, _ourDel);
        _theirDel?.DynamicInvoke(arg1);
        _tcs.SetResult(null);
    }

    protected void Observe2(Tdelarg1 arg1, Tdelarg2 arg2)
    {
        _unsub(_sender, _ourDel);
        _theirDel?.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2);
        _tcs.SetResult(null);
    }

    protected void Observe3(Tdelarg1 arg1, Tdelarg2 arg2, Tdelarg3 arg3)
    {
        _unsub(_sender, _ourDel);
        _theirDel?.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        _tcs.SetResult(null);
    }

    protected void Observe4(Tdelarg1 arg1, Tdelarg2 arg2, Tdelarg3 arg3, Tdelarg4 arg4)
    {
        _unsub(_sender, _ourDel);
        _theirDel?.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
        _tcs.SetResult(null);
    }

    protected void Observe5(Tdelarg1 arg1, Tdelarg2 arg2, Tdelarg3 arg3, Tdelarg4 arg4, Tdelarg5 arg5)
    {
        _unsub(_sender, _ourDel);
        _theirDel?.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
        _tcs.SetResult(null);
    }
}
```

The limitation of course is the number of arguments supported, and the inelegance comes from the fact that we need an `Observe{N}` method for each possible number of arguments, only one of which winds up being invoked depending on the number of arguments in the delegate type (so type parameters beyond that are just ignored and can be all set to `object`).

On its own it would be very clunky to use, but if I declare a subclass for each `object`/`event` combination I want to support, things get a lot more manageable, for example:

```
public class OneTimePropertyChangeObserver : OneTimeObserver<
    INotifyPropertyChanged, 
    PropertyChangedEventHandler, 
    object, 
    PropertyChangedEventArgs, 
    object,
    object,
    object>
{
    public OneTimePropertyChangeObserver(INotifyPropertyChanged sender, PropertyChangedEventHandler handler) :
        base(
            sender,
            handler,
            (inpc, d) => inpc.PropertyChanged += d,
            (inpc, d) => inpc.PropertyChanged -= d,
            2)
    {
    }
}
```

which can be consumed:

```
await new OneTimePropertyChangeObserver(obj, (sender, e) =>
{
    // do my thing
}).Task;
```

If anyone can think of a way to get around the argument/delegate issue and still support arbitrary `event` delegate patterns I'd definitely love to see it!